# Connection timed out when connecting to a remote tcp port

Tags: linux, centos, proxy, tcp

I have deployed my application on Linux CentOS. The app connects to a remote TCP port but it throws a connect timed out exception. I tried to connect it via telnet but the port doesn't respond.

I am completely new to Linux is there a way to add the remote ip:port to the proxy configuration file or somewhere to enable IO from that port?

Comment: Your app connects to a remote TCP port on what?  Whatever that is, it is not listening on the port.  Do you control this other device?

Answer (score 0):

The connection timeout is probably due to the fact that there is nothing listening on the other end. If you're trying to use Telnet, make sure you have the Telnet server on whatever host you want. If all you care about is the app endpoint, then make sure whatever server application you have running is running and actually listening.

As an example, say you were running an apache server, you could use:

```
service httpd status
```

to check the status of the apache server.

Additionally, I would recommend using ssh over telnet. ssh is more secure.